# Is there a reason other than browser back and forward buttons to use a router in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering if there is any other reason to use a router like React Router 4, other than being able to navigate forward and backwards in the browser?

I understand you can get params from the URL but this can also be easily handled via shared state.

Thanks

Comment: Some people develop SPAs to just be state driven to show views. So your URL never changes and if you refresh your code handles what to show based on whatever state logic you implemented. But lets say you want to have URLs that you can share with people, like localhost:8080/about or localhost:8080/contacts. With a router you can direct to specific Components buy having a routing handler.

Comment: It's easier to pinpoints why you need rr4 if you provide an example of shared state.